# What's the translation of "skip-level meeting" in French?

Tags: traduction

A skip-level meeting [is a](https://www.insperity.com/blog/skip-level-meetings-get-truly-honest-feedback-employees/):

> a meeting where a manager's manager meets directly with employees, without that manager in attendance.

What's the translation of "skip-level meeting" in French?

[Google translate](https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=fr&text=skip-level%20meetings%0A&op=translate) and [Linguee](https://www.linguee.com/english-french/search?source=auto&query=skip-level+meeting) didn't help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In France, it's called:

> **Meeting/rencontre avec son N+2** (pronounced: *N plus deux*).

Our direct manager is our [N+1](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/N%2B1), their manager our N+2, and so on up to the CEO.

On the opposite, if a manager meet employees two hierarchical levels under them, that would be:

> **Meeting/rencontre avec ses N-2** (or *N-3*, ...).

I forgot Earendelle's [***réunion***](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/50065/1109) that can be and is also used in France instead of ***meeting***.

A *meeting/réunion* is usually formal and planned, a *rencontre* is informal and often unplanned.

Answer (score 8):

I've never heard of this so I have no idea if these entries from Canadian sources are actually used in Canada but still:

> Réunion non hiérarchique ([GDT](https://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17033687))
>  Réunion sautant un niveau
> hiérarchique ([Termium](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=SKIP%20LEVEL%20MEETING&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs))

The second one could possibly be adjusted (*un, deux* etc.) like with the solution from another [answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/50064).